# Weird row styling in JavaFX Tableview (indexed-cell, :even, :odd, :selected)

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm getting some weird results using all three pseudo selectors for .indexed-cell (:even, :odd, :selected).

Suppose the following CSS:

```css
#table .indexed-cell:even {
  -fx-background-color: #f1f5f9; /* lighter grey */
}

#table .indexed-cell:odd {
  -fx-background-color: #e2e8f0; /* darker grey */
}

#table .indexed-cell:selected {
  -fx-background-color: #f0f9ff; /* blueish white */
}
```

When a row now gets selected, I would expect the :selected pseudo-class to take over and color the whole row blueish white. In reality however, the cells are grey (shade depends on the row), and only the filler part of the row (where there are no actual cells) is colored blueish white.

Commenting out the styles for :even and :odd, the whole row gets colored correctly.

<s>Edit: As requested by @James_D, I made a quick repro project: JavaFXStylingRepro.zip. Run using `./gradlew run`.</s>

Here's a screenshot to illustrate the problem (in this case, the middle row is selected):
[image: Screenshot]

Anyone got any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you create and post a [mre]?

Comment: What happens with a color having ⍺ < 1?

Comment: @James_D Yes! Will do.

Comment: @James_D Posted a repro - see my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the `indexed-cell`-class is not an optimal choice for styling the whole row, using the `table-row-cell`-class instead, everything now works.

However, this class is not documented in the JavaFX CSS Reference Guide. Lovely!